# Export and Import Customers

Tags: import, export

I've exported my customers to a CSV file. The problem is, that the _address_street has the first line of the address as well as the suburb, merged into one?

Is that normal? Is there a field for address line 2?

I'm using Magento 1.9

I tried to actually reimport that data back into Magento...and it forced everything into Address Line 1.

Answer (score 1):

Seems, this is expected behavior by design. Please, look at customer address backend model:

```
class Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Address_Attribute_Backend_Street
    extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Abstract
{
    /**
     * Prepare object for save
     *
     * @param Varien_Object $object
     * @return Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Address_Attribute_Backend_Street
     */
    public function beforeSave($object)
    {
        $street = $object->getStreet(-1);
        if ($street) {
            $object->implodeStreetAddress();
        }
        return $this;
    }
}
```

And **Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract**

```
/**
 * set address street informa
 *
 * @param unknown_type $street
 * @return unknown
 */
public function setStreet($street)
{
    if (is_array($street)) {
        $street = trim(implode("\n", $street));
    }
    $this->setData('street', $street);
    return $this;
}


/**
 * To be used when processing _POST
 */
public function implodeStreetAddress()
{
    $this->setStreet($this->getData('street'));
    return $this;
}
```

Since Module ImportExport uses attribute's backend models, so this is expected behavior.

Comment: Any idea how I can import data so it separates line1 and 2? Should I seperate them with a \n ?

Comment: Yes, you absolutely right, i.e. you should it like in **Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract::setStreet()**.

Comment: Also, please, look at following method Mage_Customer_Model_Address_Abstract::explodeStreetAddress():

    /**
     * Create fields street1, street2, etc.
     *
     * To be used in controllers for views data
     *
     */
    public function explodeStreetAddress()
    {
        $streetLines = $this->getStreet();
        foreach ($streetLines as $i=>$line) {
            $this->setData('street'.($i+1), $line);
        }
        return $this;
    }

I.e. every address street will separated as street[line number]

Comment: I'm a real beginner. I'm just cleaning some data in Excel, and trying to import it in Magento. I tried adding a \n in excel, but it didn't work. I also tried it with quotations marks - "\n" that also didn't work.

Is what your suggesting to create a column in excel called "_address_street2" ?

Comment: You can add new line in cell with help of keys combination Alt+Enter (in Windows). I've checked it once again, yes second line will merged through "\n", so add new line in Excel (as I described) and try again.

Comment: Anyone explain, what is mean "suburb", may i know what is the suburb of Victoria, Australia?